# how to detect distro / os to apply css

Tags: html, css, browser

I am currently using `<!--[if` statement to detect the type of browser the user has but i realized that the same browser (version and build) can produce different result on different operating systems.  safari shows ok on windows but distorted on ubuntu.  What is the best way to detect specific browser from specific OS, say ubuntu or debian?

Comment: _Best way_ would be to identify and fix the _problem_, instead of searching for lousy workarounds (“browser sniffing”).

Comment: without being condescending if you are trying to make a page render correctly, you are better off trying to make a one size fits all solution rather than trying to detect browser os combinations. There will be hundreds! and it becomes a management nightmare, plus ie conditional comments are no longer supported http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment .

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "distorted"? You need to ask yourself what the root cause of it is rather than blindly trying to solve it by hacking CSS for each OS/Browser combination until they work. That could take a lot of work, plus you'd need to do massive amounts of testing constantly as new OSs and browsers are released. Could it simply be a case of not having the same fonts installed? That would definitely cause page layout differences in a lot of cases, and is a common issue cross platform. But if that's the cause, your efforts will fail if people install the missing fonts on their OS.

Comment: wow. downvoted.. I do appreciate all your suggestions but i think my css is fine.  In Debian, most browsers don't seem to like times new roman and arial.  I know these aren't the best fonts, but hey, it's what my client wants.  Now, back to my question, Isn't there a simply answer to my question? How can i detect specific OS?

Comment: @SaintDee Did you check my answer?

Comment: @NOX, yes. am actually testing it now.

Comment: Note that `<!--[if` is very predictable, since it only works in IE and is ignored by all other browsers.

Comment: @SaintDee - for what it's worth, it wasn't me that downvoted you. But I maintain my point: Linux users can install Windows fonts, and a lot of them do so (myself included). Also, different linux distros provide different fonts from each other. If the problem is the fonts and you simply detect "Linux" and adjust the css without checking the fonts, then your detection code will fix the site for some linux users but break it for others, which means you're kinda defeating your own purposes.

Comment: By the way -- I note that you specifically mention the Safari browser on Linux. It's worth noting that Safari isn't officially supported on Linux at all; the user would have to be running it via Wine. That's fine, but the issue then is likely to be Wine, not Linux. Wine is very good, but does not produce perfect results for all Windows apps, and [the page about Safari on Wine](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=5293) does state that there are issues (in fact it says the more recent version hardly works at all).

Answer (score 0):

[PPK](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/) has a [great method](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html) for that:

```
var BrowserDetect = {
    init: function () {
        this.browser = this.searchString(this.dataBrowser) || "An unknown browser";
        this.version = this.searchVersion(navigator.userAgent)
            || this.searchVersion(navigator.appVersion)
            || "an unknown version";
        this.OS = this.searchString(this.dataOS) || "an unknown OS";
    },
    searchString: function (data) {
        for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
            var dataString = data[i].string;
            var dataProp = data[i].prop;
            this.versionSearchString = data[i].versionSearch || data[i].identity;
            if (dataString) {
                if (dataString.indexOf(data[i].subString) != -1)
                    return data[i].identity;
            }
            else if (dataProp)
                return data[i].identity;
        }
    },
    searchVersion: function (dataString) {
        var index = dataString.indexOf(this.versionSearchString);
        if (index == -1) return;
        return parseFloat(dataString.substring(index+this.versionSearchString.length+1));
    },
    dataBrowser: [
        {
            string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "Chrome",
            identity: "Chrome"
        },
        {   string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "OmniWeb",
            versionSearch: "OmniWeb/",
            identity: "OmniWeb"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.vendor,
            subString: "Apple",
            identity: "Safari",
            versionSearch: "Version"
        },
        {
            prop: window.opera,
            identity: "Opera",
            versionSearch: "Version"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.vendor,
            subString: "iCab",
            identity: "iCab"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.vendor,
            subString: "KDE",
            identity: "Konqueror"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "Firefox",
            identity: "Firefox"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.vendor,
            subString: "Camino",
            identity: "Camino"
        },
        {       // for newer Netscapes (6+)
            string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "Netscape",
            identity: "Netscape"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "MSIE",
            identity: "Explorer",
            versionSearch: "MSIE"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "Gecko",
            identity: "Mozilla",
            versionSearch: "rv"
        },
        {       // for older Netscapes (4-)
            string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "Mozilla",
            identity: "Netscape",
            versionSearch: "Mozilla"
        }
    ],
    dataOS : [
        {
            string: navigator.platform,
            subString: "Win",
            identity: "Windows"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.platform,
            subString: "Mac",
            identity: "Mac"
        },
        {
               string: navigator.userAgent,
               subString: "iPhone",
               identity: "iPhone/iPod"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.platform,
            subString: "Linux",
            identity: "Linux"
        }
    ]

};
BrowserDetect.init();
```

And now you have `BrowserDetect` object:

```
alert(BrowserDetect.OS);
alert(BrowserDetect.browser);
```

---

- Check the [FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/JVjew/).

Comment: this is not going to yield 100% accurate results as the useragent string can be modified. In fact we run IE 8 internally, but for some quirky reason it reports itself as IE7

Comment: @NicholasKing - re IE8 reporting as IE7: that'll be because it's using compatibility mode. You might want to fix that. But in general you're right; anything that relies on the UA string is going to potentially be a big failure. And more importantly, it doesn't actually address the real problem.